# Laravel isn't downloading on GIT BASH

Tags: php, laravel, web, git-bash

I am trying to download laravel using GIT BASH, with the prompt

```
    laravel new laravel
```

This is what it keeps showing me. And Yes! I have composer and its installed in the same directory I tried to download laravel into.

[image: This is what it shows]

Comment: Did you run `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash` first? Or `composer global require laravel/installer `?

Comment: as said by @aynber use `composer` to either require `laravel installer` or use composer to install laravel with this command `composer create-project laravel/laravel <project_name>`

Comment: @aymber I just did and it worked, Thanks! I'm having trouble downloading the laravel file though, I ran 'laravel new laravel' and it said "Could not open input file: C:\Users\Leon"

Comment: Try using `cd` to navigate to the folder where you want to put the laravel project

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have added laravel is added to your path so its accessible from anywhere.

To test it try running the command like
path/to/installation/folder/laravel new laravel

If that works then you need to move the installation folder to /usr/local/bin/laravel so that its globally accessible